# can't start apache and access phpmyadmin on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have an issue with the apache webserver and PHPMyAdmin in ubuntu.

when I open Xampp and try to start apache it doesn't start but MySQL starts.
I check error logs but there was nothing just an empty file.
here are some images:
[image]

and I check the config file and it was like this:

[image]

when I run Laravel projects it works fine like everything is ok.
but the main problem is that I can't PHPMyAdmin
here is there error image:

[image]

Maybe the problem comes from Nginx, but I am not sure about this, and how to solve this issue.

Comment: If you have nginx running, then Apache will not be able to use the appropriate port to handle traffic. You will need to decide which web server to use, or configure one of them to use a different port.

Comment: Thanks @matigo, I uninstalled Nginx and now I can apache server is running!